# How to replace integrated subtitle with external subtitle using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitle

I want to replace the subtitle present in `Stream #0:6(eng)` with an external `subtitle.ass`

video information

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2021-03-06T17:59:28.000000Z
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.29.100
Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 2464510
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:57.001000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 33015
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 424204175
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v53.0.0 ('Fool's Gold') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2021-03-06 17:59:28
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 224000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:57.408000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 43044
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 38567424
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v53.0.0 ('Fool's Gold') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2021-03-06 17:59:28
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 224000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:57.408000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 43044
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 38567424
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v53.0.0 ('Fool's Gold') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2021-03-06 17:59:28
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:3(spa): Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 224000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:57.408000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 43044
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 38567424
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v53.0.0 ('Fool's Gold') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2021-03-06 17:59:28
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:4(fre): Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 224000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:57.408000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 43044
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 38567424
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v53.0.0 ('Fool's Gold') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2021-03-06 17:59:28
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:5(por): Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 224000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:57.408000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 43044
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 38567424
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v53.0.0 ('Fool's Gold') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2021-03-06 17:59:28
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:6(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([255][255][255][255] / 0xFFFFFFFF), 1920x1080 (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : English BD PGS Sub
      BPS-eng         : 35741
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:47.742000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 692
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 6110646
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v53.0.0 ('Fool's Gold') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2021-03-06 17:59:28
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:7(spa): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([255][255][255][255] / 0xFFFFFFFF), 1920x1080
    Metadata:
      title           : Spanish BD PGS Sub
      BPS-eng         : 41766
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:47.742000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 764
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 7140737
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v53.0.0 ('Fool's Gold') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2021-03-06 17:59:28
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:8(fre): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([255][255][255][255] / 0xFFFFFFFF)
    Metadata:
      title           : French BD PGS Sub
      BPS-eng         : 36969
      DURATION-eng    : 00:20:43.492000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 586
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 5746361
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v53.0.0 ('Fool's Gold') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2021-03-06 17:59:28
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:9(por): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([255][255][255][255] / 0xFFFFFFFF), 1920x1080
    Metadata:
      title           : Portuguese BD PGS Sub
      BPS-eng         : 40091
      DURATION-eng    : 00:22:47.909000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 590
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 6855165
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v53.0.0 ('Fool's Gold') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2021-03-06 17:59:28
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i subtitle.ass -map 0 -map -0:6 -map 1 -c copy -metadata:s:s:4 language=eng output.mkv
```

- `-map 0` includes all streams from `input.mkv`.
- `-map -0:6` is a *negative map* and excludes `Stream #0:6`.
- `-map 1` includes all streams from `subtitle.ass`.
- `-c copy` enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode, so everything is just muxed and re-encoding is avoided. Like a copy and paste.
- `-metadata:s:s:3 language=eng` sets the language as English for the newly added subtitles.

  - The new subtitles are going to be added after all the others due to the order of the `-map` options.
  - There are 3 subtitles being included from `input.mkv`, so the subtitles from `subtitle.ass` will be the 4th subtitle.
  - `s:s:34` refers to `stream:subtitles:index #3`, or "the 4th subtitle stream in the output" (it starts counting from 0).

Or a more flexible but more complicated method using subtitle language metadata:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i subtitle.ass -map 0 -map -0:s:m:language:eng -map 1 -c copy output.mkv
```

- `-map -0:s:m:language:eng` is a negative map that excludes any subtitle stream from `input.mkv` that has English language metadata.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).